# ADC using MCP3008 on FPGA -

Tags: fpga, adc, vhdl, noise, shift-register

I am at the moment trying to use MCP3008 as an ADC, but for some reason it doesn't convert the output correctly. (A beginner project).

I provide it with an 3.3 V = vref = Vdd = ch0

But my output seem to never become => 1111111111 , but rather something like 1111010111...

I programming it on  a FPGA, using VHDL.

FPGa CLK : 50 mhz.

Here is the code:

```
ibrary IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.all;
use IEEE.STD_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity main is
    Port ( MISO : in STD_LOGIC;
           MOSI : out STD_LOGIC;
           CS : out STD_LOGIC;
           SCLK : out STD_LOGIC;
           CLK : in STD_LOGIC;
           );
end main;

architecture Behavioral of main is
constant N : integer := 4;
signal prescaler_counter : integer range 0 to 50000000 := 0;
signal newClock : std_logic := '0';
signal TX :std_logic_vector(N downto 0) := "11000";
signal RX : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0) := "0000000000";
type state_type is (start,state2,state3,state4,state5);  --type of state machine.
signal state : state_type := start;
signal shift_counter: integer range 0 to 750:= N;
begin

prescaler01: process(clk, newClock)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then 
        if prescaler_counter < 1000000 then 
            prescaler_counter <= prescaler_counter + 1;
        else
            newClock <= not newClock;
            prescaler_counter <= 0;
       end if;
    end if;            
end process;

SCLK <= newClock;


SPI_state: process(newClock)
begin
   if falling_edge(newClock) then      
        case state is   
            when start =>
                CS <= '1';
                MOSI <= '0';
                busy <= '1';
                RX <= "0000000000";
            state <= state2;
            when state2 => -- Send init bits. 
                CS <= '0';
                shift_counter <= shift_counter - 1;
                TX <= TX(N-1 downto 0) & TX(N); 
                MOSI <= TX(N);
                if shift_counter = 0 then 
                   MOSI <= '0';
                   shift_counter<= 12;
                   state <= state3;
                end if;
            when state3 =>
                --MOSI <= '0';
                CS <= '0';              -- Last bit init bit;
                state <= state5; 
            when state4=>
                CS <= '0';              --T_sample from falling - falling
                state <= state5;     
            when state5=>
               CS <= '0';              -- Read
               if shift_counter = 0 then
                  MOSI <= '0';
                  shift_counter<= N;
                  busy <= '0';
                  state <= start;
              elsif shift_counter < 11 then 
                RX <=  RX(8 downto 0) & MISO;
                shift_counter <= shift_counter - 1;
              else
                 shift_counter <= shift_counter - 1;
              end if;
            when others =>    
                state <= start;           
        end case;
    end if;  
end process;
```

I think my timing might be a bit off.. Eventhough i tweaked it in simulations.. So it doesn't make sense, why the output doesn't seem correct..

Help is very much appreciated :).

I know this question will get a lot of down votes, because of the level of difficulty of the question, but I have to start somewhere.

-edit-

I tried the simulation which Lincoln posted as an answer which shows that the timing, isn't off, I added a debug_tx which shows which state the program is in at the moment.

[image: Simulation]

- debug_tx := "0001"  - sets CS high, so input gets reset.
- debug_tx := "0010" - Send init bit "11000" => start bit+ peform ADC,
  input CH0.
- debug_tx := "0100" - delay - Time needed for the ADC
- Debug_tx := "1000" - delay - skip first nulbit.
- debug_tx := "1101" - read  - 9 times and perform shift values to the
  left as such.

I am pretty sure something is wrong with the way i am shifting things.. Or maybe something else..

```
  RX <=  RX(8 downto 0) & MISO;
```

Rx_Led shows the binary value of the output it reads..It seems like the last two shift gets stalled 2 clk periods each...  Which seems weird..

Side note, I am only applying the system 3.3V, but that i have pre scaled the clock down to 5- 10 hz, so it should be a problem with the timing difference from applying it 5 V or 3 V.

Comment: You had timing issues at the simulation stage?  What makes you think synthesis would be better :). Did you constrain the interface at all?  Have you tried much lower clock speeds?  How about putting a logic analyzer on the spi signals or if you don't have one use your tools to put some instrumentation on the signals and start looking at what's really going on.

Comment: Also consider that to read a bit from a spi device from an FPGA or an ASIC your output clock goes high which then travels down the delay of your trace, through the input delay of your slave device, plus the output delay time until the bit you are looking for appears on the slave output and travels back to your chip/fpga and through it's input delay to whatever register you have it connected to.  In order to capture this properly you usually have to add in your own delay here for this to work either by design or with some constraints etc.

Comment: If you look at a commercial spi controller like something from synopsys you will see they have a delay built in for this kind of thing.  Just a thought.

Comment: look at this link http://caxapa.ru/thumbs/405687/av_54019.pdf page 8 talks about delaying the rx sample time.

Answer (score 2):

I am the TA for a digital design class that uses the MCP3001 ( the single channel version of this adc) and have a testbench for debugging problems that students have with it. I modified it for your MCP3008 example. Please try testing your design with it.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity adc_tb is
end adc_tb;

architecture arch of adc_tb is

  -- Component declaration of the tested unit
  component main
    port(
      clk      : in  std_logic;
      sclk     : out std_logic;
      miso     : in  std_logic;
      mosi     : out std_logic;
      cs       : out std_logic
      );
  end component;

  -- Stimulus signals - signals mapped to the input and inout ports of tested entity
  signal sclk  : std_logic := '0'; -- the sample clock

  signal clk  : std_logic := '0';
  signal dout : std_logic := 'Z';
  signal din  : std_logic;

  -- Observed signals - signals mapped to the output ports of tested entity
  signal cs       : std_logic;
  signal adc_data : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);

  -- clock period
  constant period : time := 20 ns; -- 50 MHz clock

  -- constant data set that will be sent back as the ADC data  
  constant FIXED_DATA : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0) := std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(328,10));

  -- timing parameters from the datasheet
  constant T_HI   : time := 125 ns;     -- CLK high time
  constant T_LO   : time := 125 ns;     -- CLK low time
  constant T_SUCS : time := 100 ns;     -- CS Fall to first rising CLK edge
  constant T_DO   : time := 125 ns;  -- CLK fall to output data valid ( 125ns at 5V )
  constant T_EN   : time := 125 ns;  -- CLK fall to output enable ( 125ns at 5V )
  constant T_DIS  : time := 100 ns;     -- CS Rise to output disable
  constant T_CSH  : time := 270 ns;     -- CS disable time
  constant T_R    : time := 100 ns;     -- D_OUT rise time
  constant T_F    : time := 100 ns;     -- D_OUT fall time

begin

  ---- Unit Under Test port map
  UUT : main
    port map (
      clk      => clk,
      sclk     => sclk,
      miso     => dout,
      mosi     => din,
      cs       => cs
      );

  -- generate the clock                     
  clk <= not clk after period/2;

  -- emulate what the MCP3001 ADC is doing, by sending back some test data
  -- this process uses the timing diagram (Fig. 1) from 21293C.pdf
  process
    variable differential : boolean := false;
    variable channel_sel : unsigned(2 downto 0) := "000";
  begin
    -- Set the data line to HI-Z
    dout <= 'Z';

    -- wait until the CS is brought to '0', this starts the conversion.
    -- also check for an error where there is a rising edge that happens
    -- less than 100 ns after CS is brought to '0'
    wait until falling_edge(cs);
    if sclk = '0' then
      wait for T_SUCS;
      assert sclk = '0'
        report "Timing constraint Tsucs=100ns violated, clock rising edge must come atleast 100ns after CS transitions to '0'"
        severity error;
    else
      wait for T_SUCS;
    end if;

    -- wait for the start bit
    if din = '0' then
      wait until rising_edge(din);
    end if;

    -- handle the input mode and channel select
    -- setup and hold times are not checked
    wait until falling_edge(sclk);
    wait until rising_edge(sclk);
    if din = '1' then
      differential := false;
    else
      differential := true;
    end if;
    for i in 2 downto 0 loop
      wait until rising_edge(sclk);
      channel_sel(i) := din;
    end loop;
    if differential then
      report "sampling in differential mode on channel " & integer'image(to_integer(channel_sel));
    else
      report "sampling in differential mode on channel " & integer'image(to_integer(channel_sel));
    end if;

    -- sample time...
    wait until falling_edge(sclk);
    wait until falling_edge(sclk);
    wait for T_EN; -- small delay time after falling edge from datasheet
    dout <= '0';

    -- output the converted data MSB first after every falling edge.
    -- also check for a likely problem where the CS is not held at '0' while
    -- reading all 10 bits of data.
    for i in 9 downto 0 loop
      wait until falling_edge(sclk);
      wait for T_DO; -- small delay time after falling edge from datasheet
      dout <= FIXED_DATA(i);
      assert cs = '0'
        report "CS needs to be held at '0', not all bits have been transmitted"
        severity warning;
    end loop;

    -- wait for CS to go back high then disable the output
    wait until rising_edge(cs);
    wait for T_DIS;
    dout <= 'Z';

    -- wait for the minimum delay time before the start of the next sample.
    -- also check for a likely error, where CS is only '1' for a single
    -- 320ns clock period
    wait for T_CSH-T_DIS;
    assert cs = '1'
      report "Timing Constraint Tcsh=350ns violated, CS needs to be held to '1' for atleast 350ns before transitioning to '0'"
      severity error;

  end process;

end arch;
```

Comment: Thanks for the TB, is it set for an input voltage being 5 V or 3.3V, as this would affect the timing aswell...

Comment: I changed a bit.. but it doesn't seem to giving me the wanted output on the hardware as the simulation shows me.

Comment: Please look at my update.

Comment: What's funny is I had this problem the last time that I did the lab and I had wired up the ADC incorrectly. Check that. Also for your simulation you may want to output the data in your shift register so that we can check if it is working correctly. The testbench I gave you returned 328 as the ADC data ( fixed_data). Verify that you are getting that value. It looks like this was changed since the simulation shows fixed_data=1023.

Comment: Please look at my update.. 

RX_LED shows the output when  each bit gets left shifted. 

I linked Vdd = Vref = CH0 to the same pin, which should give me a binary output of "1111111111"... which it does sometimes, but the response isn't as stable as i thought it would be..

Comment: It seems like i read a 0 bit after the first null bit,  it could be due to me reading the values at falling edge, rather than rising_edge..Creating the delay of it reading 0 rather than the just set value.

Comment: could it be the missing T_suck time?

Comment: I've added the T_suck timing.. Which improved it a lot, when i look at it with a freq. of 3.57 it's perfect => LED wise, but when i set the time down, it gets some error between the conversions...

Comment: Have you tried doing a post place and route timing simulation with that testbench? It might give you a better idea of what is going wrong.

Comment: I am not sure on how to do that?

Comment: http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx11/pp_p_process_simulate_post_place.htm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30755/discussion-between-lincoln-and-carlton-banks).